# Javascript HTML DOM select

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding HTML element selection using javascript.

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
<script>
    function changeText() { 
        document.getElementsByClassName("CentralContainer")[0].getElementsByClassName("PlayFlowSelect")[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = "Custom Stream";
                }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="CentralContainer">
        <div class = "PlayFlowSelect">
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/ArrowLeftIcon.png" onclick="changeText()">
            <h2> Top Stories </h2>
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/ArrowRightIcon.png" onclick="alert('Trigger Upload Page')">
        </div>
```

For some reason my selection path in my javascript isn't selecting the h2 innerHTML. I'm not sure why... Any help?

Comment: Probably you're selecting a text node (space between elements). Try to get the `nodeType` of the node retrieved

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to select an element this way. If for some reason you put some other html element before the `<h2>` tag, your code will not work properly. Something like @atmd's answer looks better to me.

Comment: @Al.G. I agree - this is likely to break in the long term.  JLRishe's answer explains well why it isn't _currently_ working though, and is the correct answer in this instance.  Using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) would be better still, as you could just use `document.querySelectorAll('.CentralContainer .PlayFlowSelect h2')`

Comment: @JamesThorpe OK, I agree. JLRishe explains the real reason how it works, but if I had to do it, I would do it atmd's way.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, the `childNodes` property includes *all* child nodes, including text nodes, which would mean that the `h2` you want would be `childNodes[3]`.

You can use the [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) property to get just element children:

```
function changeText() { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("CentralContainer")[0]
            .getElementsByClassName("PlayFlowSelect")[0]
            .children[1].textContent = "Custom Stream";
}
```

But as other answers and comments have suggested, this is not the cleanest or most reliable way to do this.

Comment: What is the difference between textContent and innerHTML?

Comment: The difference is that `el.textContent = '<b>Hi!</b>';` would display `<b>Hi</b>` in the page, while `el.innerHTML = '<b>Hi!</b>';` would display **Hi!** in the page. The best practice is to avoid `innerHTML` unless you _specifically_ treat a value as HTML. `innerHTML` creates a risk for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities and other problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it slightly to get the H2 element by the tag name

```
document.getElementsByClassName("CentralContainer")[0].
getElementsByClassName("PlayFlowSelect")[0].
getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML;
```

Reads a bit cleaner (IMO) then more array node indexes and avoid additional id's

Answer (score -1):

Give the `<h2>` tag an ID and call `getElementById()`

```
function changeText() { 
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "test";
}

<div class="CentralContainer">
        <div class = "PlayFlowSelect">
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/ArrowLeftIcon.png" onclick="changeText()">
            <h2 id="header"> Top Stories </h2>
            <input type="image" src="./Home Page Resources/ArrowRightIcon.png" onclick="alert('Trigger Upload Page')">
        </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helped.
Best regards